# How to use httpclient (. Net) to specify an IP to access the HTTPS URL

Tags: c#, httpclient

How to use `httpclient (. Net)` to specify an IP to access the `HTTPS` URL without modifying the hosts file. And IP can be updated at any time, similar to:

```
curl -- resolve web.smp.com:443 :111.111.111.111
```

Comment: I'm guessing you mean C# instead of C right?

Comment: It is not clear to me what the actual problem is.  Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example, what you expect and what you actually get.

Comment: if all you need is to connect to a particular DNS host why not use the DNS name?